# Permission denied - numpy.loadtxt?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a python script which polls a folder to see if a new file is added, and when a new file is added, it loads the text file into numpy.

```
before = dict([(f, None) for f in os.listdir('.')])
while 1:
    #time.sleep(10)
    after = dict([(f, None) for f in os.listdir('.')])
    added = [f for f in after if f not in before]

    if added:
        print added[0]
        try:
            raw = numpy.loadtxt(added[0])
        except IOError:
            print "----- Error"
            core.wait(0.1)
            raw = numpy.loadtxt(added[0])
```

When I don't try catching the exception, I get an error in reading the file - "Permission denied". I am a Windows administrator, so this should not be an issue. It also only happens on some files, so I think the script might be trying to open the file before it is fully written. Is there any way to get rid of this error?

Comment: You could open the file separately, and pass the file object to `loadtxt`.  Of course you would need to close it as well (use a `with` context to ensure that).  It may not solve the timing issue, but it will let you focus on that.  Linux allows multiple readers, Windows is pickier about sharing.

Comment: Just tried that; looks like I'm getting the error (Errno 13) with the `with open(myfile.txt) as f:` also.

Comment: Then you need to either live with the delay, or figure out who isn't closing the file in a timely manner.

Comment: I'm testing out my script by copying and pasting a text file in Windows - so it's Windows that's not closing it in a timely manner.